# Cargo not found after installing in a devcontainer

Tags: rust-cargo, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I have a `.devcontainer.json` for GitHub Codespaces but when I run `cargo` in the `postCreateCommand` it states that cargo isn't found.

Below is my `.devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Cargo",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:jammy",

    // Install Cargo when the devcontainer is made.
    "onCreateCommand": "curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y",

    // Install Cargo dependancies.
    "postCreateCommand": "cargo install aftman",
}
```

The specific log from the `creation.log`:

```
2024-03-24 21:44:44.709Z: cargo install aftman
2024-03-24 21:44:44.771Z: /bin/sh: 1: cargo: not found
2024-03-24 21:44:44.797Z: postCreateCommand failed with exit code 127. Skipping any further user-provided commands.
```

When I run `cargo` in the codespace's terminal it works fine and I can install cargo dependancies there but I want it to install cargo automatically when I open the codespace.

Note that the codespace works fine and doesn't go into recovery mode at all so nothing else should be wrong.

I tried making it so that bash terminal restarts but that just made it so my codespace never loaded.